# VS 2019 generates AllowNull for struct IEquatable

Tags: visual-studio-2019, c#-8.0

I created a struct that I'm going to use as a key of a Dictionary like so:

```
public struct PairKey : IEquatable<PairKey>
{
```

When I use visual studio to "Implement Method", it generates an empty Equals method that has an [AllowNull] attribute for the parameter.

```
public bool Equals([AllowNull] PairKey other)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();     
}
```

I'm assuming this doesn't make sense for a struct parameter.  Is this a bug in the code generator and is it safe to remove the AllowNull in this instance?

I'm using VS 2019, version 16.3.8.

Comment: The [actual reported bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39243) is `PairKey`. It should be `PairKey?`. We write code that compares variables and fields to `null` all the time. `Equals([AllowNull] PairKey other)` would break this code.

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos.  From the bug report, it will be fixed in v16.5.  However for my use-case, a Dictionary<Tkey, the definition says `where TKey : notnull`, so it doesn't make sense to me to use PairKey? in Equals, because the generic parameter PairKey is not nullable.